# getting the records with better quality field

Tags: mysql, select, having

i have the above table

```
 create table wardrive 
    (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    mac varchar(50) not null,
    ssid varchar(100),
    lat varchar(20),
    lon varchar(20),
    rssi int,
    quality int,
    channel int,
    privacy varchar(20),
    hora varchar(30),
    primary key(id)
    )
```

On this table I've some mac address of wireless access point, the coordinates, the quality of the signal and so on.
I need to get 3,4, 5 records of each mac, that have the better quality of signal, and get the coordinates (lat, lon) with it

```
select mac, lat, lon, quality
from wardrive
group by mac, quality;
```

I try to filter with having max, but no success... and i'm thinking... it would only return the better quality... and not 3, 4, n better results

Comment: post example input data & expected output result

Answer (score 0):

I think a rank function should work for you

```
SET @rank:=1; 
SET @mac := null;
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT @rank = IF(@mac = mac , @rank+1, 1) as rank, 
 @mac:=mac as mac , lat, lon, quality
 FROM wardrive
 ORDER BY mac, quality
) AS t WHERE rank <=3 ; ## the number you have to have
```

Answer (score 0):

this have solved my problem

```
set @num := 0, @mac := '';

select ssid, mac, quality, lat, lon, privacy
from 
(
   select *,
      @num := if(@mac = mac, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @mac := mac as dummy
  from wardrive
  order by mac, quality desc
) as w 
where w.row_number <= 3
order by quality desc;
```

Example

```
mac        quality       lat           lon        privacy
'00:1F:6D:A7:D4:D6','80','-21.116403','-47.78662','WEP'
'00:1F:6D:A7:D4:D6','79','-21.116382','-47.786582','WEP'
'00:1F:6D:A7:D4:D6','69','-21.116508','-47.786841','WEP'
'00:2A:E7:B3:DE:32','69','-21.120032','-47.787511','WPA'
'00:2A:E7:B3:DE:32','67','-21.116821','-47.787466','WPA'
'00:2A:E7:B3:DE:32','54','-21.116781','-47.787468','WPA'
'0A:22:BC:A8:E2:EA','84','-21.117334','-47.786619','WPA2'
'0A:22:BC:A8:E2:EA','84','-21.117396','-47.786617','WPA2'
'0A:22:BC:A8:E2:EA','68','-21.117823','-47.786794','WPA2'
'54:E6:52:F5:1C:32','24','-21.119308','-47.787254','WPA2'
'54:E6:52:F5:1C:32','24','-21.119308','-47.787254','WPA2'
'54:E6:52:F5:1C:32','10','-21.117118','-47.78716','WPA2'
'5C:52:1F:1B:84:50','38','-21.117697','-47.786715','WPA2'
'5C:52:1F:1B:84:50','38','-21.117823','-47.786794','WPA2'
```